# Convert int to double in AVX x86

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, masm, avx

I have an external function:

```
extern "C" void calculateAreaUnderCurve_(double startPoint, double endPoint, int numberOfTrapezes, double* coefficients, double* result);
```

I'd like to convert `numberOfTrapezes` to a `double` in my .asm file.

I tried with: `vcvtsi2sd` and `cvtsi2sd` but It doesn't work.

Edit:

Here is my .asm file

```
.model flat,c    
.code

;   Function declatation:
;   int calculateAreaUnderCurve_(double startPoint, double endPoint, 
;   int numberOfTrapezes, double* coefficients, double* result);

calculateAreaUnderCurve_ proc
        push ebp
        mov ebp,esp

;   Load argument values
        vmovsd  xmm1,real8 ptr [ebp+8]      ;xmm1 = startPoint
        vmovsd  xmm2,real8 ptr [ebp+16]     ;xmm2 = endPoint
        mov     ebx, [ebp+20]               ;ebx  = numberOfTrapezez int value
        mov     eax, [ebp+28]               ;eax  = pointer to coefficients array
        mov     ecx, [ebp+32]               ;ecx  = pointer to result

        cvtsi2sd xmm3,dword [ebp+20]        ;convert to double
        movsd real8 ptr [ecx],xmm3          ;save result
        pop ebp
        ret
calculateAreaUnderCurve_ endp
        end
```

And my function call:

```
int numberOfTrapezes=100;
//initialize other parameters
calculateAreaUnderCurve_(startPoint,endPoint,numberOfTrapezes, coefficients, &result);
```

As a result i get strange number `1.0761e+09`

Comment: You probably crash from clobbering ebx.  Just use `vcvtsi2sd` with a memory operand, if you're writing code for a crappy calling convention like 32bit x86 that passes args on the stack.

Comment: What CPU are you using ? `vcvtsi2sd` is AVX-512, not AVX.

Comment: @PaulR I'd have another look at the instruction set reference if I were you.

Comment: I have updated my question with the full .asm file code and function call.

Comment: @EOF: hmm - must be a bug in the online intrinsics guide then: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=vcvtsi2sd

Comment: @PaulR: `vcvtsi2sd` is just the VEX-encoding [of the SSE2 instruction](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=cvtsi2sd).  For some reason there are new intrinsics for the EVEX encoding of it without the rounding-control override, even though they still haven't changed the stupid semantics (merge into an existing reg, instead of zeroing the upper half to break the dependency chain for the common scalar use-case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> vmovsd  xmm1,real8 ptr [ebp+8]      ;xmm1 = startPoint
> vmovsd  xmm2,real8 ptr [ebp+16]     ;xmm2 = endPoint
> mov     ebx, [ebp+20]               ;ebx  = numberOfTrapezez int value
> ```

You are retrieving the *numberOfTrapezez* from the wrong address! The *endPoint* occupies 8 bytes, so change the offset from 20 to 24.

```
mov ebx, [ebp+24]
```

and also

```
cvtsi2sd xmm3,dword [ebp+24]        ;convert to double
```